# Good way to create own button component (Primary button, Secondary button etc.)

Tags: css, angular

I'm new in Angular and I do not even know if this approach is good.
I want to create my own universal button component and define his styles in `button.component.css`. After i want to use this button in my other component like login form.

I do something like that in `button.component.css`:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.primary-button {
  background: #5c52ff;
  color: white;
}

.primary-button:hover {
  background: white;
  border: #5c52ff solid 2px;
  color: #5c52ff;
}

.secondary-button {
  border: forestgreen solid 2px;
  background: white;
  color: forestgreen;
}
```

Now in `index.html` i do:

```html
<app-button class="primary-button"></app-button>
```

But scope of `button.component.css` works only in `button.component.html`

I should to create this style classes in global `style.css` and don't create button component but simple use button tag and add class attribute with property from `style.css`. How to approach this problem.

Comment: @Spenser Truex I now how to style this elements :) I do not know how to solve this problem architecturally

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking. You should edit your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting the class to the button present in your `button.component.html` instead of setting it in the `app-button` element. You can achieve this by sending your class to the button component as an `Input`.

**index.html**

```
<app-button className="primary-button"></app-button>
```

**button.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
....

  @Input() className: string;
```

**button.component.html**

```
<button [class]="className"></button>
```

This way your class will be applied within the scope of `button.component.css`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So from an architectural point of view, creating components in this way is a good practice?